# Does Judaism believe that Moshe (Moses) is the last Prophet?

Tags: history, moshe-rabbeinu, nevua-prophecy

Does Judaism believe that Moshe (Moses) is the last Prophet?  Is this suggested in the Torah? If he was not the last prophet, but the Torah seems to suggest it, what does that mean?

Comment: All of the books of prophets are later than the torah, so no.  Moshe is the *greatest* of the prophets because he encountered God face-to-face, but he's certainly not the last.

Comment: You already asked about other prophets and found out that there were many who came after Moses http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22946/759

Comment: no , my Withdrawal of that question and answers only number of them and name of them. I can't find out anything about last of them or like that.

Comment: Ok but you knew it wasn't Moses. If you want to ask who the last one was, you can do so but it already has been done here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17727/759

Comment: OK I read that article and other answers but did not understand things because full of difficult terms and unknown names. and complex. we want (wish) to answer us simple

Comment: @MonicaCellio, DoubleAA is this better?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you are thinking of [Deuteronomy 34:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0534.htm#10): "And there hath not arisen a prophet since in Israel like unto Moses" (OJPS). However, he was certainly not the last prophet; in fact the previous verse refers to Joshua being a prophet. Similarly, there are tons of prophets after Moses later in the [Tanach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanakh). The verse in Deuteronomy simply means that Moshe was the greatest of all the prophets.