# Does Judaism recognize contemporary prophets?

Tags: navi-prophets, nevua-prophecy

Some new religions, like the Baháʼí Faith, believe in relatively recent prophets.

Some Christian sects, like The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints (informally known as Mormons and often seen as heretics by the rest), believe in continuing revelations. They believe that prophets are still coming.

Most Christians believe that prophets ended some time after Jesus. The Catholic Church believes that public revelations already ended but private prophecy is still ongoing.

Some Christian leaders, such as Benny Hinn, believe that they are prophets.

How does Judaism see the possibility of ongoing or contemporary prophets or prophecy?

Are there still prophets in Judaism? I am not able to find an answer anywhere, but I heard some say that Malachi was the last prophet.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17727/759

Comment: @DoubleAA duplicate?  If recent/modern prophets were possible then the answer to that question would be "still open" or "don't know yet", right?

Comment: The statements of the gentile religions are violations of the prohibition agains false prophets [Deuteronymy 13:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9977#v2)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The last of the true prophets (nevi'im) were indeed Chaggai, Zechariah, and Malachi. The Talmud (Bava Batra 12a) cites:

> R. Abdimi from Haifa said: Since the day when the Temple was destroyed, prophecy has been taken from the prophets and given to the wise.

i.e. the wise can predict the future using their wisdom, but not through *nevua* - prophecy.

(The Talmud [Bava Batra 12b] also cites Rabbi Yochanan that since the destruction of the Temple, prophecy was given over to children and the mad.)

Comment: That's just an opinion of the rabbi. Is there anything more authoritative about that? Or what is the rabbi reasoning

Answer (score 4):

A prophet is not just an intuitive or clairvoyant individual. Of those we have plenty. The Rambam describes the initiation of a Navi as a rigorous test. He must be very precise. If he says that a certain event will happen at two o'clock next Thursday and it happens at three, he is not a prophet. There are no such people around.

Now, although Nevua stopped, there were other levels of divine communication that remained. Nevua is clear communication, where a Navi will speak in the name of Hashem. Ruach Hakodesh is divinely guided awareness. There were lucid dreams throughout the generations and there is גלוי אליהו, where אליהו הנביא reveals himself to a worthy individual and teaches him Torah.

In summary, we recognize the existence of people that can predict or advise but true prophecy just hadn't happened yet.

Answer (score 1):

In Guide for the Perplexed 2:36 [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) writes:

> The same circumstance, prevalence of sadness and dulness, was
>   undoubtedly the direct cause of the interruption of prophecy during
>   the exile: for can there be any greater misfortune for man than this:
>   to be a slave bought for money in the service of ignorant and
>   voluptuous masters, and powerless against them as they unite in
>   themselves the absence of true knowledge and the force of all animal
>   desires? Such an evil state has been prophesied to us in the words,
>   "They shall run to and fro to seek the word of God, but shall not find
>   it" (Amos viii. 12); "Her king and her princes are among the nations,
>   the law is no more, her prophets also find no vision from the Lord"
>   (Lam. ii. 9). This is a real fact, and the cause is evident; the
>   pre-requisites [of prophecy] have been lost. In the Messianic
>   period--may it soon commence--prophecy will therefore again be in our
>   midst, as has been promised by God. ([Friedlander translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp123.htm))